# How to get button element of asp.net in iframe?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have HTML page having iframe in it.

I am taking asp.net  page in ifrmae. That asp.net page also have a master page.

I am not able to fetch button text of my asp.net page  in my html page

please suggest javascript/jquery

Thanks in advance..

this is my iframe in my html page

```
<iframe runat="server" scrolling='no' frameborder='0' id="iframe1" style="width: 100%">
```

i am assigning path to iframe in  this way

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').src = "default.aspx"
```

where button is in default.aspx..this page also have a master page

Comment: You want to access the button inside an iframe from an aspx page?

Comment: from html page where iframe is

Comment: can you provide code for `Button` and `Iframe`. so we can know name and other attributes.

Comment: and what is the code for button?

Comment: please see my update above

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("iframe1").src = "WebForm1.aspx";
        $('#iframe1').load(function () {
            var iframe = $('#iframe1').contents();

            iframe.find("#Button1").click(function () {
                alert("test");
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: no its not working..it is giving error access is denied

Comment: hi i tried your code in other project..but problem is that in my project i am loading another project/solution...so i think i am getting error access is denied..please suggest

Comment: where did you place the code in default.aspx or iframe placed page?

Comment: in iframe placed page like this 
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("input[type='button'][id$='btnSubmit']").click(function () {
             //  alert();
               $('#iframe1').contents().find('#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnback1').click(function () { alert('21212'); });
               //               $('#iframe1').contents().find(document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_btnback1')).click(function () { alert(); });
           });
       });
  </script>

Comment: still it is working only if page is in same project..i am loading page of another project

Comment: ...this solution worked for me...thanks......@KarthikManoharan....you are the man.....

Answer (score 1):

**`KarthikManoharan`** is Leading you to the right way...

but what I suppose missing is, ID of the Button. Dynamically your `Button ID` is changed by the server every time you compile application.

So you need to prevent that first by adding  `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your button.
like :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

now you can access this button in your IFrame like:

```
 $('#iframe1').contents().find('#Button1')          // Access Button

 $('#iframe1').contents().find('#Button1').html()   // Return Text of Button

 $('#iframe1').contents().find('#Button1').click(function(){       });  // Events
```

Try this code. and let us know if you find any discrepancy.

Comment: thanks for your response...html() is giving null and click is giving error access is denied..please suggest some thing